# What's the difference between an abstract class with implemented method and service in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

Lets say we have an abstract class with implemented method that HomeComponent extending it and a service with the same code that we inject into component. Is there any difference in our case? if yes what is the differences if no when to use abstract class vs service

```
abstract class Base {
    name: string = "";

    getName(){
       return this.name;
    }
} 


 @Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent extends Base implements OnInit {


}
```

vs

```
@Injectable()
export class BaseService {
    name: string = "";

    getName(){
       return this.name;
    }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
  providers: [BaseService]
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private baseService: BaseService) {}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Abstract classes are usually created for as a "base" class on which to extend from. They also can't be instantiate on their own.
When you extend a class (abstract or not), the properties of said class will be available directly on the class that extends it. So for example, you would be able to access getName as such:

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent extends Base implements OnInit {
  constructor(){
     super();
     this.getName();
  }
}
```

If you instead make the base class an injectable, then you have to access it from that injected class instance.
Also note worthy is that when you make a class `Injectable`, then that class will effectively become a singleton and have the same state throughout all places you provide it in whilst extending the abstract base class will be tied to the specific class that extends it.

As a side note, you can't have abstract classes Injectable.

So when to use what?
It very much depends on what you want to achieve. Making abstract classes are mainly for structuring your code in a more OOP manner. If the intention is that the Base class is shared between different injections then make it Injectable and not abstract.

You can read more about abstract classes here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#abstract-classes-and-members